# How can I make the iOS badge count match the number of notifications in the notifications centre?

Tags: ios, react-native

My client has two options for how they want the badge count to operate:

Ideal would have been to that the badge count matches the number of notifications in the notification centre associated with the app client-side, but iOS doesn't give you that count, and I can't track it via just counting because they might clear notifications/notifications might expire.

Alternatively, they would like the app not to clear the notifications when you reset the badge count to 0. It appears that iOS also does not give you *that* option, as resetting the badge count to 0 automatically clears the notification centre for your app.

I'm working in react-native, but could drop into native code to resolve this if necessary.